# CSS. Flexbox. Можно ли добиться такого поведения?

Tags: css, вёрстка, веб-программирование

Можно ли с Flexbox добиться такого поведения?

[image: Пример]

Разумеется, с media-queries.
Из проблем столкнулся с тем, что не смог задать элементам свойство, чтобы они были на второй строке. Подогнать ширину не получается из-за блоков фиксированной ширины.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да. Использовать `order` для переупорядочивания и `flex-grow` для расширения. Не уверен, но может понадобиться добавить лишний элемент в разметку (или использовать псевдоэлемент контейнера) для форсирования перевода строки.

https://jsfiddle.net/rw8o4tc8/3/

```css
html, body { margin: 0; }

body {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 240px;
}

.a, .e { background: aquamarine; } /* top */
.b, .d { background: burlywood; } /* bottom */
.c, .f { background: silver; } /* center */

.a, .b, .d, .e { flex-grow: 1; }
.c { width: 100px; }
.f { width: 50px; }

@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  .a, .c, .e {order: -1; }
  body:before { content: ""; width: 100%; }
  .b { order: 1; }
  .f { order: 2; }
  .d { order: 3; }
}
```

```html
<div class=a>sizable top</div>
<div class=b>sizable bottom</div>
<div class=c>100px</div>
<div class=d>sizable bottom</div>
<div class=e>sizable top</div>
<div class=f>50px</div>
```

Comment: >для форсирования перевода строки
С этим и проблема. Но новые мысли появились, спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: @DTXqueque, с этим нет проблемы. `width:100%` ему просто и он займёт целую строку.

Comment: Не очень понял, что это значит, но, похоже, в соседней ветке нашёл похожий ответ.
Добавить пустой div с width:100%. Не пойму, написано 100%, а он просто пропадает.
Но всё равно спасибо!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732575/line-break-in-multi-line-flexbox

Comment: @DTXqueque, я позже кодом покажу. Сейчас занят.

Comment: @DTXqueque, ответ обновлён.

Comment: опечатка. eidth -> width. Если исправить, то немного ломается)
http://i.imgur.com/SnuJ2yW.png

Comment: @DTXqueque, на так минимальную ширину тоже надо пересчитать. Я не делал ничего, чтобы гарантировать конкретное значение. И ничего, чтобы обеспечить равную ширину блоков.